# HREF link that targets nothing, does not want to use hash or void(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link that I want to be able to click to trigger a piece of jQuery code.

Currently I have

```
<a href="#" id="foo">Link</a>
```

and

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
  // Do stuff
});
```

which works well. But, I have always hated using hash in this way. The page flickers and the hash is added to the page url.

One alternative is to use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="foo">Link</a>
```

but I also dislike seeing that piece of code in the browser status bar. It looks tacky.

---

What I'd rather have is an explanatory javascript placeholder that does nothing, like

```
<a href="javascript:zoom();" id="foo">Link</a>
```

which actually works, but throws an ReferenceError in the javascript console since there are no such function. **What's the minimum definition of a function that does nothing?**

**Are there any other alternatives?**

**Should I just skip the link and use something like**

```
<span id="foo" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">Link</span>
```

**instead?**

Comment: For accessibility reasons, I wouldn't recommend using a span that's styled like an anchor.

Comment: You probably want to use `<a href="#zoom">` combined with @patrick dw's answer.

Comment: @thirtydot That's it! Spot on.

Comment: @ScottE What do you mean with "accessibility"? Like, website experience for users with features disabled or surfing through mobile devices?

Comment: Screenreaders for blind users won't know that a _visually_ styled span is supposed to be a link.

Comment: @Mattis - yes, like Eevee said. A span won't be able to take a focus (active) like an anchor. So, keyboard navigation won't work.

Comment: @Eevee - screen readers will also be confused with links that aren't links. The appropriate UI component is a button, then both sighted and unsighted visitors will know that it isn't a link *before* they click on it.

Comment: @ScottE @Eevee @RobG I get it, good points, thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`event.preventDefault()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method.

```
$('#foo').click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
  // Do stuff
});
```

This will prevent the hash from having any effect when you click. Or get rid of the hash, and use CSS to style it.

Also, you can provide an actual url for the `href` to handle graceful degradation.

---

> **What's the minimum definition of a function that does nothing?**

Here's a no-op function:

```
var noop = function(){};
```

...or since you're using jQuery, you can use the [`jQuery.noop()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/) method, which also is just an empty function.

```
$.noop
```

Comment: +1:  Note that with this answer u can keep the hash tag and the page wont flicker.  javascript:void(0) is depricated.

Comment: But how can you style the link like a link? Is there a way to access the CSS color of a link that it has by default when a href is set?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, the link should link to a page that replicates the JavaScript functionality for users without JS enabled.  Then `preventDefault` would prevent the actual navigation, as the other answers have indicated.

If that doesn't make sense in this case, note that the `href` attribute is optional.  You can just leave it off entirely.

Comment: If the href attribute is omitted, element is no longer a link.

Comment: It's not really a link if it goes to a dummy location anyway.  You're probably right about using a button.

Answer (score 3):

This is an inappropriate use of a link, you should be using a button or some other element that indicates that clicking will make something happen but not navigation.

Comment: Agreed but in this case the link is attached to a graph and it's obvious that the link will do a zooming action on the graph object due to the naming and placing of the text. Also, buttons would be too big in this implementation. In general, you are perfectly right though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), for instance:

```
$('#foo').click(function(e){
    // Do stuff
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This won't work. preventDefault() is a method of the event, not the jQuery-wrapped element that was clicked.

Comment: @Rob Cowie: Honest mistake - correct, though a little late, bet than never.

Comment: Assumed it was a simple mistake. :)